# ExcelJS doesn't add image

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, javascript-objects, exceljs

I'm trying to add an image using exceljs,
but when I try to add the image there is an error fs.readFile is not function. This is the error in console.[image]
and this is my code for add image to excel.

```
 const imagePath = path.resolve('img/logo.jpg');

        const imageId = workbook.addImage({
           filename: imagePath,
           extension: 'jpg'
        });

        worksheet.addImage(imageId, 'B3:C3');
        worksheet.mergeCells('B3:C3');
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
// add image to workbook by buffer
const imageBuffer = await axios.get('path/to.image.png', { responseType: 'arraybuffer' });
const imageId2 = workbook.addImage({
  buffer: imageBuffer.data,
  extension: 'png',
});
```

[enter link description here](https://github.com/exceljs/exceljs/issues/1244)